# Some specific calculation in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

how do I make a calculation based on the result of a previous line in R?
To make it more clearly, just imagine the following dataframe:

```
user   rev   total_rev
A      10    10   
A      10    20 
A      20    40
A      10    50
B      50    50  
C      50    50   
C      10    60
C      20    80
```

where user is an unique ID variable and rev a metric variable (for example revenue), which I want to aggregate into the new variable "total_rev". It should contain the sum of the variable "rev" up to the specific line, thus someting like the following calculation has to be conducted for each line:

```
> total_rev[i] = total_rev[i-1] + rev[i]
```

where i is the actual line

Note that the calculation has to start from zero for each user. I've already tried to solve this with a loop, which worked for a small testcase, but the dateframe is quite huge and the calculation on the complete data set just didn't want to end.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This question is very straightforward and should be resolvable from some quick research on your part. `R` is vectorized and has wonderful aggregation tools.  Look around a bit on here and google for `cumulative sums` and the `split-apply-combine` strategy of data manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
mydata<-mtcars
ddply(mydata,.(cyl),transform,mpg=cumsum(mpg))
```

For your data:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(yourdata,.(user),transform,total_rev=cumsum(rev))

 user rev total_rev
1    A  10        10
2    A  10        20
3    A  20        40
4    A  10        50
5    B  50        50
6    C  50        50
7    C  10        60
8    C  20        80
```

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with huge database, `data.table` is a good option

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(df)
> DT[, total:= cumsum(rev), by=list(user) ]
> DT
   user rev total_rev total
1:    A  10        10    10
2:    A  10        20    20
3:    A  20        40    40
4:    A  10        50    50
5:    B  50        50    50
6:    C  50        50    50
7:    C  10        60    60
8:    C  20        80    80
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `?ave` and `?cumsum`:

```
ave(df$rev, df$user, cumsum)
```

E.g.:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("user   rev   total_rev
A      10    10   
A      10    20 
A      20    40
A      10    50
B      50    50  
C      50    50   
C      10    60
C      20    80"), header=TRUE)

df$total <- ave(df$rev, df$user, cumsum)
#  user rev total_rev total
#1    A  10        10    10
#2    A  10        20    20
#3    A  20        40    40
#4    A  10        50    50
#5    B  50        50    50
#6    C  50        50    50
#7    C  10        60    60
#8    C  20        80    80
```